# Singular/Plural agreement

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one of the following is correct?

1. Each employee wanting their workday adjusted or time off to vote must request it from their supervisor.  or
2. Each employee wanting his/her workday adjusted or time off to vote must request it from his/her supervisor.

Thanks

GeorgeV

Comment: You already asked this - [*Which is correct - singular “they” or “his/her”?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110130/which-is-correct-singular-they-or-his-her). Why ask it again?

Comment: @user3169 He may want to know the agreement between "each employee" and "their" as a plural pronoun or his or her as singular pronoun. My answer address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

> If necessary, change the subject from singular to plural. When you are
>   referring not to a specific individual but to a type of individual,
>   you can avoid both gender-specific pronouns and the incorrect use of
>   the pronoun "their" by using a plural subject. [(The source)](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaGender_Neutral_Language.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a grammar question, it's a style question.

Currently, the "The Chicago Manual of Style" has been updated to accept 'their' as in your sentence.

The "New York Times" style manual still does NOT accept 'their' in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using gender-specific pronouns "his/her" you can use "their", but it doesn't make it plural.

Regarding the title of your question, you need a singular pronoun for "each employee" because you consider them individually and not as a whole.

I think in your sentence you should use "any" instead of "each" because they could be from zero to all the employees who may have such a request and you don't care who or how many they are.

"Each" is used when you want to say that an action is performed individually by the whole members of a group.

> each employ should focus on their (his/her) task